# OS X: How to pass mouse drag events through a view to superview

Tags: swift, macos

I am building an app using Swift for OS X where I have a `NSTabView` that I can drag images into.  For each image that is dragged in, it adds a new tab and the `NSTabViewItem` contains a `NSImageView` that holds the `NSImage` that was dragged in.

I created a subclass of the `NSTabView` class that handles the drag operations.

I have the code working where it is taking the dragged images and creating the new tabs correctly.  However, once there is an `NSImageView` showing (after dragging in), now, when dragging new images, it appears the `NSImageView` is blocking the dragging information and does not receive the drag operation. Therefore, I can only drag new images if i put them at the edge just over the `NSImageView` showing the previously dragged image.

Is there a way to make the `NSImageView` transparent to the mouse drag events so that they pass through to the `NSTabView` below?

I have tried setting `NSImageView.enabled` to false, and also trying to override the `hitTest` of the `NSImageView`.  But none of these seem to be working.

Comment: Is the `NSImageView`'s `editable` property set to `false`? `editable`: "A Boolean value indicating whether the user can drag a new image into the image view." https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImageView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSImageView/editable Not sure if that will work or not...

Comment: @NSGod The `NSImageView` is created programatically.  I printed out the value of `editable` after creation and it appears to be set to `false` by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function on `NSView`

`func unregisterDraggedTypes()`

on the `NSImageView` that you create to stop them from eating up the images on the pasteboard.

That should allow the underlying `NSTabView` subclass to receive the drag events.

Alternatively if thats not working, place a `NSView` subclass which will receive the drag events over the top of the `NSTabview` and override the `hitTest` so clicks get through to the views underneath.

```
override func hitTest(aPoint: NSPoint) -> NSView? {
    return nil
  }
```